# Could not click on the buttons in SlidingDrawer

Tags: android

I have a problem with SlidingDrawer. All buttons in it could not be click.

Here is my xml file for SlidingDrawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_video"
            style="@style/button_menu_bottom"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/mnu_video"
            android:text="@string/video" />

        ...
        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Here is my java file extended from SlidingDrawer

package com.example;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
import com.example.R;

public class BottomMenuBar extends SlidingDrawer {

    private SlidingDrawer mSlidingDrawer;
    private Button mButtonSlidingDrawer;
    private LinearLayout mLayoutContent;
    private Button mButtonVideo;
    private Button mButtonPhoto;
    private Button mButtonChat;
    private Button mButtonSetting;

    public BottomMenuBar2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(infService);
        li.inflate(R.layout.bar_bottom_menu, this, true);
        mSlidingDrawer=(SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.sld_bottom_menu);
        mButtonSlidingDrawer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.handle);
        mLayoutContent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
        mButtonVideo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_video);
        mButtonSetting=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_setting);
    }

    public Button getmButtonSlidingDrawer() {
        return mButtonSlidingDrawer;
    }
    public void setmButtonSlidingDrawer(Button mButtonSlidingDrawer) {
        this.mButtonSlidingDrawer = mButtonSlidingDrawer;
    }

    ...
    Setter & Getter methods
    ...     
}
```

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >

        ...
        Any content
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.example.BottomMenuBar
            android:id="@+id/sld_bottom_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my buttons in sliding drawers, I tell each button what method to use in the xml with `android:onClick`.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sortbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="SortClickHandler"
            android:text="@string/sd_sortmethod_button"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
```

And then define the method in whatever activity is appropriate:

```
public void SortClickHandler(View v) {
    //  Do stuff here
}
```

**EDIT**

I think I found your issue.  From the developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) it says, and I quote:

```
SlidingDrawer should be used as an overlay inside layouts. This means SlidingDrawer 
should only be used inside of a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout for instance.
```

So, I think if you change your layout to a RelativeLayout you will find that your buttons will work.  I just double-checked all of my uses of a sliding drawer and in all cases the root element of the view containing it is a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Perhaps your style or soething else is interfering.  Try with just a plain old button, get rid of the style and the drawable and insert a width and height and see what happens...

Comment: I think I found your issue.  Updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I found the problem, but not found solution yet.
The problem come from BottomMenuBar class. Because when I test with raw xml, it's ok.
Thanks for your reply. If I found solution, I will post again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're extending `SlidingDrawer`.

You should look up the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

```
<SlidingDrawer
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

 android:handle="@+id/handle"
 android:content="@+id/content">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@id/handle"
     android:layout_width="88dip"
     android:layout_height="44dip" />

 <FrameView
     android:id="@id/content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
   [INSERT VIEWS HERE]
 <FrameView>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

In your `Activity` you don't even technically need to gain access to the `SlidingDrawer` object (The sliding functionality is already in place as standard, it simply contains the the view's in `content`, you don't need to interfere).

From your `Activity` gain reference to the view's you add in [INSERT VIEWS HERE]. You can then do `setOnClickListener()` on each of these buttons.